# Ask for a power UP bullets in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to powers up my spaceship bullet when I take some thing like a gift I have tried a lot but nothing okay :( can any one help me please
I have tried to but this code but it's never work for me an I am search in a lots of web sites just I get that then my ship is destroyed as its destroyed when it's hit the enemies any help for my question please:)

my ship code is :

```
 public GameObject shot;
public int coolDown = 0;
public int typeshoot = 1;
public Vector3 shotPosotion;
private GameObject forO;
public int computer = 0;
void Start()
{
    forO = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("forO");
}

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (Input.GetButton("Fire1"))
    {
        if (computer <= 0)
        {
            shotPosotion.x = this.gameObject.transform.position.x;
            shotPosotion.y = this.gameObject.transform.position.y + 0.8f;
            shotPosotion.z = this.gameObject.transform.position.z;
            switch (typeshoot)
            {
                case 1:
                    GameObject instance = (GameObject)GameObject.Instantiate(shot, shotPosotion, this.gameObject.transform.rotation);
                    break;
                case 2:
                default: break;
            }
            computer = coolDown;
        }
    }
    computer -= 1;
}
}
```

and my gift as a power up code is:

```
  using System.Collections;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using UnityEngine;

   public class powerUp : MonoBehaviour
  {
private int computer=300;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{

}

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (computer <= 0) {
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }
    computer -= 1;
}
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.name== "PlayerShip"){
        other.gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerShooting>().typeshoot += 1;
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }
}
  }
```

Comment: any one can help me?